# Could facebook minimize the number of servers if they used a faster database rather than MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql, rdbms

Facebook needs 30,000 Servers to run. Seriously that's a lot!
Facebook is old. It uses MySQL.

I was wondering if they started with a much faster and efficient database, my question:
 1. What database would that be?
 2. What would be an estimate on
    how much servers it could save?

Comment: Only 30K?  Facebook has contributed several performance fixes to MySQL; don't knock them.  Part of the 30K is redundancy -- how often does FB go dark?  Part of that 30K is for speed -- how often is a page slow at loading?  Etc.

Comment: No.  Source: Google my name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "faster database". You can do some pretty outrageous corner cutting and scalability hacks with MySQL using some clever architecture design to gain huge performance advantage. Far more so than with any other mainstream database.

Anybody who suggests to you that you can gain better performance if you switch to a different database without looking at the full details of the actual workload that needs to be performed, is a charlatan with no actual understanding of databases or computer systems in general.